# Targeting the next several siblings with CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I would need to find element by data attribute, apply some CSS to it, but also apply it to another several siblings next to it.

I have tried something like this, but it will apply only for the element with data attribute.

```
.fc-widget-header[data-date='2020-07-20T00:00:00']:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+5) { color: #f00; }
```

I have also tried this, but it will apply css only for the first sibling of my element with data-attr.

```
.fc-widget-header[data-date='2020-07-20T00:00:00'] + .fc-widget-header:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+5) { color: #f00; }
```

I need to apply to elements like this, for example for the first X elements (the number of elements is variable).

```
<th class="fc-widget-header" data-date="2020-07-20T00:00:00" colspan="2">
  <div class="fc-cell-content"><span class="fc-cell-text">po 20.</span></div>
</th>
<th class="fc-widget-header" data-date="2020-07-21T00:00:00" colspan="2">
  <div class="fc-cell-content"><span class="fc-cell-text">út 21.</span></div>
</th>
<th class="fc-widget-header" data-date="2020-07-22T00:00:00" colspan="2">
  <div class="fc-cell-content"><span class="fc-cell-text">st 22.</span></div>
</th>
<th class="fc-widget-header" data-date="2020-07-23T00:00:00" colspan="2">
  <div class="fc-cell-content"><span class="fc-cell-text">čt 23.</span></div>
</th>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for the *general sibling combinator* (`~`).

```css
.fc-widget-header[data-date='2020-07-20T00:00:00'] ~ th {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <th class="fc-widget-header" data-date="2020-07-20T00:00:00" colspan="2">
    <div class="fc-cell-content"><span class="fc-cell-text">po 20.</span></div>
  </th>
  <th class="fc-widget-header" data-date="2020-07-21T00:00:00" colspan="2">
    <div class="fc-cell-content"><span class="fc-cell-text">út 21.</span></div>
  </th>
  <th class="fc-widget-header" data-date="2020-07-22T00:00:00" colspan="2">
    <div class="fc-cell-content"><span class="fc-cell-text">st 22.</span></div>
  </th>
  <th class="fc-widget-header" data-date="2020-07-23T00:00:00" colspan="2">
    <div class="fc-cell-content"><span class="fc-cell-text">čt 23.</span></div>
  </th>
</table>
```

Essentially, the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) (`~`) targets all subsequent siblings.

Note the distinction with the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) (`+`), which targets only the next sibling.